# Applying a boost::mpl::list to the template parameter of a type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl, boost-variant

I have a class that requires a boost::variant containing shared pointers to various types as follows:

```
template <typename ToySharedPtrVariant, typename ColorSharedPtrVariant>
class ToyPicker {
   typedef std::pair<
     ToySharedPtrVariant, 
     ColorSharedPtrVariant 
   > toyAndColorPair;
   typedef std::map<
     std::string,
     std::vector< 
       toyAndColoPair 
     > 
   > stringToToyColorPairMap;

   // ... methods that use the defined types...
}
```

This class currently requires template parameters of the following form to compile:

```
ToyPicker<
           boost::variant<
             boost::shared_ptr<ToyModel> 
           >,
           boost::variant<
             boost::shared_ptr<BlueToy>,
             boost::shared_ptr<RedToy>,
             boost::shared_ptr<GreenToy> 
           > 
         > toyPicker;
```

How do I use an mpl list so that I can allow the following much simpler definition for users, then convert it into the example format above inside my class implementation?

```
ToyPicker<
       boost::mpl::list<
         ToyModel
       >,
       boost::mpl::list<
         BlueToy,
         RedToy,
         GreenToy 
       > 
     > toyPicker;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [boost::mpl::transform](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/transform.html) in conjunction with [boost::make_variant_over](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/make_variant_over.html) does the trick :

```
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>

template<class T>
struct add_shared_pointer
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> type;
};

template<class Seq>
struct shared_ptr_variant
{
    typedef typename boost::make_variant_over<
            typename boost::mpl::transform<
                Seq, add_shared_pointer<boost::mpl::_1>
            >::type
        >::type type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [boost::make_variant_over](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/make_variant_over.html) it does what you need.

Comment: boost::make_variant_over will create a variant<T1,T2...>, not a variant<shared_ptr<T1>, shared_ptr<T2>... >

Comment: right, kudos to icecrime for being much more thorough than me :)